# First Betti number definition

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

I found in the electric engineering literature this alternative definition of the *first Betti number* of an open set $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^3$ with Lipschitz boundary.

$n_\Omega$ is the first Betti number of $\Omega$, i.e. the number of *independent* non-bounding cycles in $\Omega$,

where

> we say that a finite family $\mathcal{F}$ of disjoint cycles in
>   $\Omega$ is formed by *independent cycles* if for each non-empty
>   subfamily $\mathcal{F}'$ of $\mathcal{F}$, the union of the cycles of
>   $\mathcal{F}'$ cannot be equal to the boundary of a surface contained
>   in $\Omega$.

Do you think it is correct?

Assuming it is correct, then I'd like to know what it is the meaning, in terms of homology, of the following definition.

$\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^3$ bounded connected Lipschitz set such that:

- $\exists$ $\Omega_C$ open so that $\overline{\Omega}_C\subset\Omega$ and $\Omega_I:=\Omega\setminus\overline{\Omega}_C$ is connected
- $\Gamma:=\partial\Omega_I\cap \Omega_C$. Note that $\partial\Omega_C=\Gamma$ and $\partial\Omega_I=\partial\Omega\cup\Gamma$

$n_\Gamma$ is the number of $\partial\Omega$-independent non-bounding cycles in $\Omega_I$, where

> we say that a finite family $\mathcal{G}$ of disjoint cycles in
>   $\Omega_I$ is formed by *$\partial\Omega$-independent cycles* if for
>   each non-empty subfamily $\mathcal{G}'$ of $\mathcal{G}$, the union of
>   the cycles of $\mathcal{G}'$ cannot be equal to
>   $\partial S\setminus\gamma$, $S$ being a surface contained in
>   $\Omega_I$ and $\gamma$ a disjoint union of curves, possibly empty,
>   contained in $\partial\Omega$.

Comment: You have substantially changed the question. In the future, please don't do that. If your question has two parts, start with both parts of the question.

Comment: You are absolutely right @MikeMiller, I'm sorry. If you want, I can split it into two questions

Comment: @MikeMiller is it a sort of relative homology?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, at least morally. Note that a sufficiently nice basis for $H_1$ gives you (after maybe a small perturbation) a collection of independent cycles under this definition. On the other hand, a collection of independent cycles clearly gives you linearly independent elements of $H_1$. I assume the conditions given take care of any possible technical issues with this relationship.

Comment: You need to add a condition about linear independence, otherwise I can put as many 'independent cycles' as I want in the open solid torus. Given that, though, it's literally true.

Comment: The union of two of them would bound an embedded surface then, though, right?

Comment: No, I mean eg pick a loop $\gamma_i$ that winds around the torus exactly $i$ times. Then neither of say $\gamma_1 - \gamma_2$ or $\gamma_1 + \gamma_2$ jointly bound a surface. I need to be able to take $2\gamma_1 - \gamma_2$.

Comment: Oh, that's right. It seems that this definition assumes cycles can only have winding number 1. Or whoever wrote it didn't fully grasp the subtleties of homology.

Comment: Assuming that the author meant the cycles to have winding number $1$, what do you think about the definition of $\partial\Omega$-independence I added above?

Comment: I'm skeptical about this winding number 1 business, too. Why can't I take an open solid genus 2 handlebody and consider loops representing $(0,1), (1,1), (1,-1)$? I think they need to have an explicit condition about winding number 1.